# How to make polygonal vector artwork

Tags: android, vector, android-imageview, polygon

I am trying to find a way to make [image: this]

type of vector but I have no idea how to make it I have seen in many splash screen of the app any hint will be helpful .

Comment: One method I can think of immediately is to draw various polygons in different colours with transparent alpha values. The polygons will superimpose and generate something like in your image. Of course, you'll need to implement some sort of colour control, because if it's completely random, it won't look as nice as your example.

Comment: I dont think thats a good idea as in one app its done in the splash screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `<vector>` drawable and paint a bunch of semi-transparent shapes. Here's an example:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="360dp"
    android:height="160dp"
    android:viewportWidth="360.0"
    android:viewportHeight="160.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M0 0h360v160h-360z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M0 0h48L0 60z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M0 160V40L100 50L140 160z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M70 0L80 140L300 0z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M300 0L280 160H360V0z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M320 0L340 160H360V0z"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M100 0L100 50L260 160H360V0"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3000"
        android:pathData="M0 160L80 140LL120 160"/>

</vector>
```

This is obviously not as beautiful as your attached image, but it shows that the general technique works to create an image like the one you posted.

[image]

Comment: how i can set the different path? if i want multiple like this